# What's an efficient algorithm to calculate line breaks (word wrap) for balanced widths (minimum raggedness)?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, performance

*This is a real-world application, not a student assignment.*

- Suppose we have some numbered boxes which are to be laid out, **in order**, from left to right, top to bottom, with no space between them, into a column of fixed width and infinite height.
- The boxes have the same height, but variable width.
- When a box doesn't fit, it should wrap to the next line (just like text).
- After that, we **fix the number of lines**, and then lay out the boxes again so that the lines have a more *balanced* width, which means they try to be the same width, as much as possible.

The input is, simply:

```
double colWidth = …;
List<double> boxWidths = [ … ];
```

And the output could be:

```
List<int> result = [ … ]; // Number of boxes in each line.
double minWidth = …;
```

An example: Suppose the column has width = 11, and 5 boxes have widths [2, 3, 5, 2, 1], then the layout is this:

```
| ** *** ***** |
| ** *         |
```

This means we can fit the boxes into 2 lines, and line widths differ a lot. One is 10 and the other is only 3 (difference is 7).

Now we have to lay them out again in 2 lines, to achieve balanced width:

```
| ** ***       |
| ***** ** *   |
```

The result is 2 boxes in the first line, and 3 boxes in the second line: `List<int> result = [2, 3]`. Widths are now 5 and 8. Difference is 3, and `minWidth` is 8.

Please note, we **cannot change their order**. If we could, then the difference would be 1 and `minWidth` would be 7:

```
| ** *** *     |
| ***** **     |
```

---

**My question:**

**What's the most efficient algorithm to solve this? I am interested in speed, and I don't care about memory usage.**

Comment: You'll have to decide how you want to measure how different the lengths are.  Do you want to use max - min?  Standard deviation?  Something else?

Comment: @D.W. I know I want some "visually balanced" outcome for this, but I wouldn't know exactly how to define it. Maybe I could find the average line width, and then sum the square of the difference between the width of each line to this average. Maybe. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: You might want to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer to give at least everyone around the globe a chance to answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you considered using the total-fit line breaking algorithm[(a)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap) used by TeX[(b)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) and developed by Donald Knuth and Michael Plass?

- Donald Knuth and Michael Plass. ["Breaking Paragraphs into Lines"](http://www.eprg.org/G53DOC/pdfs/knuth-plass-breaking.pdf).

  - https://github.com/jaroslov/knuth-plass-thoughts/blob/master/plass.md
  - https://github.com/baskerville/paragraph-breaker
  - https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~dberry/ATEP/StudentLectures/Ananya.pdf
  - https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1134342
  - https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb21-3/tb68fine.pdf
- Remco Bouckaert. ["A Probabilistic Line Breaking Algorithm"](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~remco/line.pdf).

Edit:

The total-fit line breaking algorithm has already been implemented in many languages, including Java:

- ["Knuth & Plass line-breaking Revisited"](https://blog.csdn.net/maimang1001/article/details/23301287) in Java
- ["The linebreaking algorithm of Knuth and Plass"](https://web.archive.org/web/20060813210058/http://www.leverkruid.nl/GKPLinebreaking/index.html) in Java (via [Generalized Knuth-Plass Linebreaking Algorithm](http://apache-fop.1065347.n5.nabble.com/Generalized-Knuth-Plass-Linebreaking-Algorithm-td22245.html))
- ["rosettacode: Word wrap"](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Word_wrap) has implementations of the Knuth Plass algorithm in a variety of languages

Comment: The Knuth-Plass algorithm is also used in Adobe InDesign.

Comment: Wow, that paper is a fascinating reading, thanks for pointing it out. However, I am not really formatting text, but only boxes, with no space between them. So the concepts of hyphenation and shrinking and expanding glue make no sense in my case. I will soon need another version with spacing, but that's another question. Well, I guess that algorithm could work in both cases, but I just searched now and couldn't find a Java or C# version. I wouldn't really know how to translate from Rust or C. Translating that other one from Python was already troubling for me.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved with dynamic programming; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap#Minimum_raggedness or https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/lecture-20-dynamic-programming-ii-text-justification-blackjack/ for resources.

Comment: Do these take into account the fact that the number of lines is fixed?

Comment: @MarcG yes, they can easily handle that constraint.